# Как организовать очередь потоков

Tags: c#, многопоточность, task, очередь

Как сделать последовательное выполнение методов?

Есть метод `Method_A` и `Method_B`, они должны выполниться последовательно: сначала `Method_A` затем `Method_B`, причем если метод выдал ошибку, не выполнился, или возникли еще какие-либо проблемы, необходимо повторить выполнение метода.

Метод А

```
static void download()
{
    Console.WriteLine("Beginning to download results..");
    FtpClient ftp = new FtpClient();
    sFTP sftp = new sFTP();
    ftp.PassiveMode = true;
    int TimeOUT = 1000;

    do
    {
        ftp.Connect(TimeOUT, "host", 21);
        ftp.Login(TimeOUT, @"log", "pass");
    }
    while (ftp.IsConnected == false);

    ftp.ChangeDirectory(TimeOUT, @"directory");

    foreach (FtpItem item in ftp.GetDirectoryList(TimeOUT))
    {
        if (item.ItemType == FtpItemType.File && !System.IO.File.Exists(@"path" + item.Name))
        {
            ftp.GetFile(TimeOUT, @"path" + item.Name, @"path" + item.Name);
            Console.WriteLine("Скачан файл - " + item.Name);
        }
    }
    ftp.Disconnect(TimeOUT);

    Console.WriteLine("The results have been downloaded");
}
```

Метод В

```
static void upload()
{
    Console.WriteLine("Beginning to upload files to FTP-server..");
    FtpClient ftp = new FtpClient();
    sFTP sftp = new sFTP();
    ftp.PassiveMode = true;
    int TimeOUT = 1000;

    do
    {
        ftp.Connect(TimeOUT, "host", 21);
        ftp.Login(TimeOUT, @"log", "pass");
    }
    while (ftp.IsConnected);

    var dirLocal = new DirectoryInfo(@"directory");и
    foreach (FileInfo file in dirLocal.GetFiles())
    {
        string fileName = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(file.FullName) + Path.GetExtension(file.FullName);
        ftp.PutFile(TimeOUT, "path" + fileName, @"path" + fileName);
        Console.WriteLine("Файл - " + fileName + " " + "загружен на FTP сервер");
        string spath = @"path" + fileName; 
        string dpath = @"path" + fileName; 
        File.Move(spath, dpath);
        Console.WriteLine("Файл - " + fileName + " " + "перемещен");
    }
    ftp.Disconnect(TimeOUT);

    Console.WriteLine("The files have been uploaded to FTP server");
}
```

Comment: Так и пишите: `a(); b();` - методы выполнятся последовательно. При чём тут многопоточность?

Comment: `Task.Run && ContinueWith` Помогут?

Comment: Возможно имеет смысл добавить сюда Ваши наработки, чтобы получить более конкретный ответ на вопрос, основываясь на Вашем коде.

Answer (score 3):

На самом деле, если смотреть на то, как Вы описали задачу, то потоки здесь действительно не при чём. Нужно просто в цикле выполнить несколько раз по очереди каждый метод. Дождавшись положительного результата выполнения, начать циклически выполнять второй метод. Если неудачным результатом выполнения метода считать возникшее в нём исключение, то можно решить задачу примерно так:

```
class Program
{
    static void MethodA()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Executing method A");
        Thread.Sleep(1000);
        //раскомментируйте для проверки
        //throw new NotImplementedException("ERROR!");
        Console.WriteLine("Method A executed");

    }

    static void MethodB()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Executing method B");
        Thread.Sleep(2000);
        //раскомментируйте для проверки
        //throw new NotImplementedException("ERROR!");
        Console.WriteLine("Method B executed");
    }

    static void ExecudeMethodInLoop(Action method, String methodName)
    {
        Boolean success = false;
        while(!success)
        {
            try
            {
                method.Invoke();
                success = true;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"Method {methodName} execution failed. Reason: {ex.Message}");
                Console.WriteLine($"Method {methodName} execution restart...");
            }
        }
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        ExecudeMethodInLoop(MethodA, "A");
        ExecudeMethodInLoop(MethodB, "B");
    }

}
```

**UPD** вариант для метода с параметром типа Int32:

```
static void ExecudeMethodWithParameterInLoop(Action<Int32> method, Int32 parameter, String methodName)
        {
            Boolean success = false;
            while(!success)
            {
                try
                {
                    method.Invoke(parameter);
                    success = true;
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine($"Method {methodName} execution failed. Reason: {ex.Message}");
                    Console.WriteLine($"Method {methodName} execution restart...");
                }
            }
        }
```

В последнем случае используем делегат типа Action, параметризированный типом параметра, который нужно передать в метод, соответствующий делегату. Можно использовать несколько параметров, например:
`Action<String, Int32, Byte>`, в таком случае метод будет принимать три параметра разных типов (`String`, `Int32`, `Byte`), и все они будут доступны в методе `Invoke()`. Если Вам нужно ещё и возвращать значение, можно использовать делегат `Func<>`.

Comment: Сделал как вы сказали, первый метод выдал "Timeout occurs", и сразу начал свое выполнение следующий метод. Так быть не должно..Суть программы состоит в том, что первый метод - скачивает файлы с фтп-сервера, а второй - закачивает. Второй метод ни в коем случае не должен выполняться пока первый корректно не выполнился.

Comment: Приведите в вопросе код своего приложения. Ту часть, что отвечает за upload/download.

Comment: надеюсь, это поможет

Comment: Если timeout occurs - это текст исключения, возникшего в методе, то все должно работать, если Вы конечно правильно написали метод ExecuteMethodInLoop

Comment: Откуда Вы получаете сообщение timeout occurs ?

Comment: Timeout occurs - это текст исключения. Ваш метод ExecuteMethodInLoop, честно говоря, просто копировал и вставил

Comment: Вы не подскажите, как передать параметр в таком случае?

ExecudeMethodInLoop(MethodA(parametr), "A")

Comment: Обновил ответ..

Comment: `причем если метод выдал ошибку, не выполнился, или возникли еще какие-либо проблемы, необходимо повторить выполнение метода` сделайте чтобы первый метод возвращал bool, и возвращайте true когда он выполнится, только после этого выполняйте второй